# Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261

Tags: phpmyadmin

I got an error after installing new ubuntu server. 
The error is located at phpmyadmin. The complete error are the following below:

```
Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261
mysqli_query(): (22003/1690): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(unix_timestamp() - 18446744073709550663)'

Backtrace

./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 18446744073709550663',
integer 0,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#244: PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 18446744073709550663',
object,
integer 1,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#1887: PMA_DatabaseInterface-
>tryQuery(
string 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 18446744073709550663',
object,
integer 1,
boolean false,
) 
./libraries/server_status.lib.php#53: PMA_DatabaseInterface-
>fetchValue(string 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 18446744073709550663')
./libraries/server_status.lib.php#25: 
PMA_getHtmlForServerStateGeneralInfo(object)
./server_status.php#35: PMA_getHtmlForServerStatus(object)
```

All update are downloaded but I still get this error. I tried reinstalling phpmyadmin but the same issue. 
This server is a newly installed server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for me.

1. Explore to `xampp/phpMyAdmin/`
2. open `config.sample.inc.php` in a text editor
3. uncomment all storage database.and tables from:
   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';`
   to
   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';`
4. then restart the server.

I hope it also helps you. cheers!